# Django let User Update TextField value on Site via forms?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, forms

I hope someone can give me a little help on how to do the following with Django (excuse me if I don't explain everything correct, still new to Django and don't know about a lot of things) :

I have a table of Movies, those Movies have a "Description" Datafield, where when they click on it a form opens up with the current description of the movie. If they double click on this description they are allowed to change it and then save the value. I've made a small gif to visualize the idea:

[image]

At least thats the basic Idea behind this, so far I've managed to make most of the things run, but sadly not the Django part where the "new" data from the user is send to the Databank and replaces the old data of the Description.

So could someone explain to me how I can make that work? I know that I'd probably have to write a function to my views.py and then create a new url pattern, but I just can't figure out how exactly. So any help is welcome! Below is my code (I hope I've included every file you guys need):

**views.py**

```
 from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
 from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
 from django.urls import reverse
 from django.views import generic
 from django.views.generic.list import ListView
 from .models import *

 class AllMovies(generic.ListView):
     model = Movie
     template_name = "consilium/index.html"
     context_object_name = "latest_movie_list"

 class MovieDetails(generic.DetailView):
     model = Movie
     template_name = "consilium/detail.html"
```

**urls.py**

```
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from . import views
 from .models import *
 from django.views.generic.list import ListView

 app_name = "consilium"
 urlpatterns = [
     url(r'^$', views.AllMovies.as_view(), name="index"),
     url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_0-9]+)/$', views.MovieDetails.as_view(), name='detail'),
 ]
```

**models.py**

```
 from django.db import models
 from decimal import Decimal
 from django import forms
 from django.contrib import admin

 class Movie(models.Model):
     // removed the other models for better overview
     description = models.TextField('Movie Description')

     def __str__(self):
         return self.title
```

**index.html**

```
 {% extends "consilium/base.html" %}

 {% block body %}
     <table class="table">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th></th>
                 <th colspan="2">My Movielist</th>
                 <th>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <th></th>
                 <th>TITLE</th>
                 <th>GENRE</th>
                 <th>RELEASE DATE</th>
                 <th>DIRECTOR</th>
                 <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                 <th>RUNTIME</th>
                 <th>STATUS</th>
                 <th>IMDB</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
             {% if latest_movie_list %}
                 {% for movie in latest_movie_list %}
                 <tr>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>
                         <a href="{% url 'consilium:detail' movie.slug %}" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left" data-content='<img class="title-image" src="{{movie.image.url}}"/>'>{{ movie.title }}</a>
                     </td>
                     <td>{{ movie.get_genre_display}}</td>
                     <td>{{ movie.date}}</td>
                     <td>{{ movie.director}}</td>
                     <td id="icn-change" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".demo{{ forloop.counter }}">
                     Description <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                     </td>
                     <td>{{ movie.runtime}} min</td>
                     <td>{{ movie.get_status_display}}</td>
                     <td>{{ movie.imdb}}</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td></td>
                     <td class="hiddenRow" colspan="8">
                         <div class="container collapse demo{{ forloop.counter }}">
                             <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                 <div class="col">
                                     <form method="post" id="usrform">{% csrf_token %}
                                         <textarea id="text" class ="form-control" readonly="true" onkeydown="expandtext(this)" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';">{{movie.description}}</textarea>
                                     </form>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                 <div class="col align-self-start">Double Click to Edit</div>
                                 <div class="col align-self-end">
                                     <input type="submit" id="set" class="pull-right"/>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
                 {% endfor %}
                 {% else %}
                     <tr>
                         <td>No Movies are available.</td>
                     </tr>
             {% endif %}
         </tbody>
     </table>
 {% endblock %}
```

**script.js**

```
 // removed all other code for overview

 // replace description text with user input
  $('#set').click(function() {
      var test = $('#text').val();
      localStorage.setItem("test", test);
  });

  $('#text').text(localStorage.getItem("test"));
```

I hope I didn't miss anything, thanks for everyone who can help me!

Comment: You are trying to *update* an existing Movie instance. Check [UpdateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview) in the docs.

Comment: Thanks, gonna give it a read :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to the great help of the pythondev slack community!

views.py: getting the description field of my Movie Model

```
 class MovieUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Movie
         fields = ['description']
```

reverse_lazy is important, so that when I click on my button it won't redirect me to consilium(my appname)/2/update and stays on the index site where I have my table

```
 class MovieUpdateView(UpdateView):
     model = Movie
     form_class = MovieUpdateForm
     success_url = reverse_lazy('consilium:index')
```

urls.py:

```
 url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/update/$', views.MovieUpdateView.as_view(), name='movie_update'),
```

here it was important to put this before my slug url pattern I had in my urls.py, otherwise it didn't work:

```
 url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w_0-9]+)/$', views.MovieDetails.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

My form in my html: using pk=movie.pk so it will grab the correct movie and giving my textarea the name of "description" so my method knows where the data is coming from

```
 <form action="{% url 'consilium:movie_update' pk=movie.pk %}" method="post" id="usrform">{% csrf_token %}
      <textarea id="text" class ="form-control" name="description" readonly="true" onkeydown="expandtext(this)" ondblclick="this.readOnly='';">{{movie.description}}</textarea>
      <input type="submit" id="set" class="pull-right"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a similar project, and here is what I did.

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict

@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    profile, created = ClientProfile.objects.get_or_create(user_id=request.user.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileSubmissionForm(request.POST, instance=profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('jobs:list'))
    else:
        profile_dict = model_to_dict(profile)
        form = ProfileSubmissionForm(profile_dict)
        return render(request, 'jobs/profile.html', {'form': form})
```

Essentially, the `model_to_dict` renders the values stored in the database in the form. The `instance=profile` makes sure I'm updating the form and not creating a new object.

Comment: Hey, first of all thanks for that! Could you explain the code for me a little more detailed? I'm kinda new to the whole Python/Django Topic and don't know everything yet :) I tried to use you're code in my model, but it didn't quite work, even the console didn't give back any error messages. Also wouldn't I have to add something to my urls.py and change my javascript file?

Comment: `def edit_description(request):
    description, created = Movie.objects.get_or_create(movie_id=request.movie.id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = usrform(request.POST, instance=description)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('consilium:index'))
    else:
        profile_dict = model_to_dict(description)
        form = usrform(profile_dict)
        return render(request, 'consilium/index.html', {'form': form})`

Tried to understand the code you gave me a little, is that the correct use?